# How can I read json file to collect the attribute values in different companies?

Tags: python, arrays, json

As the question explained above, I faced the difficulty of reading json file to collect attribute values from the company database in Python, and would like to store the values into numpy.ndarray form. What I wanna do is to read through
all the companies numbering and select its own values.

For example:

```
"0000059745": {
        "Income": 5928375,
        "Assets": 958273479,
}

"0000212498": "Empty dictionary.",
    "0000310826": {
        "Income": 1928474,
        "Assets": 2938479,
}
```

However, the relevant questions I checked on other sources were simply basic instruction of teaching people how to read json file with the same name for a single company, but did not explicitly have the similar problem as I had.

For instance:

```
"comp1": {
        "Income": 5928375,
        "Assets": 958273479,
}

"comp1": "Empty dictionary.",
    "comp1": {
        "Income": 1928474,
        "Assets": 2938479,
}
```

Hence, what I would like to do it is something like below:

```
with open("input/company_data.json") as f:

for comp in companies["number"]:
    for var in company_variables["Assets"]["Income"]:
    // Storing both Assets and Income attribute values into dataNdArr as numpy.ndaarray type
    dataNdArr = var
```

I hope someone could help me with further improving this deeper level of reading json file problem.
Thank you.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file. The objects need to be in an array, with `,` between them.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. Why are all of the companies `comp1`?

Comment: What are `companies` and `company_variables`?

Comment: `company_variables["Assets"]["Income"]` doesn't make sense. That means that `company_variables["Assets"]` is a dictionary, and `Income` is one if the keys in that dictionary.

Comment: Maybe you mean something like `company_variables["Assets"] + company_variables["Income"]`

Comment: I just provided an example of the companies in a dictionary, because other web sources simply teach how to obtain values in the same company.

companies and company_variables are simply the example of variables I am going to use.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. Do you just want to replace the company number keys like `0000059745` with the corresponding company names? Do you have another dictionary with the mapping between names and numbers? If so, you can do it with a trivial dictionary comprehension.